# Allocate data at specific address in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

I was browsing around for stuff to do and I got the idea to allocate memory at specific addresses in windows.

So I read a few questions here on stackoverflow, but none actually presenting a working example, so I had to come up with my own because I really wanted to try:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Variable {
    int var;
};

#define ACCESS() ((Variable*)0x50000000)

int main()
{
    DWORD ptr;
    VirtualAlloc((void*)0x50000000,sizeof(Variable),MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE | MEM_PHYSICAL,PAGE_READWRITE);                    
    VirtualProtect((void*)0x50000000,sizeof(Variable),PAGE_READWRITE,&ptr);
    ACCESS()->var = 5;
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState('Q')){}
}
```

But this alway causes an access voilation..

What is the correct way to allocate data at a specific address?
Because, this way somehow won't work.. yet confusing at the same time with "Why not?".

---

Edit:

Second code after first answers not working too:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Variable {
    int var;
};

#define ACCESS() ((Variable*)0x50000000)
int main()
{   
    std::cout << VirtualAlloc((void*)0x50000000,sizeof(Variable),MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    ACCESS()->var = 6;
    std::cout << ACCESS() << std::endl;
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState('Q')){}
}
```

the return value is 0, which indicates failure and the GetLastError() equals 487,

and 487 according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) means:

ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS;
Attempt to access invalid address.

So, all I read over the internet and stack overflow is fake? You >Cannot< allocate data at a specified address? And if this is true, why do we need this function anyway?

---

Next edit:

Seems it's totally possible, working code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Variable {
    int var;
};

#define ACCESS() ((Variable*)0x50000000)
int main()
{   
    std::cout << VirtualAlloc((void*)0x50000000,sizeof(Variable),MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    std::cout << ACCESS() << std::endl;
    ACCESS()->var = 6;
    std::cout << ACCESS()->var << std::endl;
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState('Q')){}
}
```

Comment: You allocate memory at `0x50000000` but then try to modify memory at `0xDEADBEEF`. Even if you had successfully allocated memory at the specified address, you'd still get an access violation at a totally different address. Also, you can't set memory protection or allocate virtual memory in such small chunks. Protection and virtual allocation is of pages of memory. (Please read the docs for [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), your code makes no sense.)

Comment: oh sry I changed them accordingly in my code, the ACCESS define is just for this code snippet which I forgot to change xD Anyway thanks for spotting /updated :)

Comment: Your call to `VirtualProtect` still tries to set the protection on a non-existing mapping.

Comment: The OS is greedy ya know, just like its crea... well, at least it's preventing you from keeping doing those crazy stuff. ;-)

Comment: @David reversing the 2 lines doesn't work too, updated the code ;o

Comment: Such an old question of mine.. I was SOO stupid haha. Nonetheless an interesting question. I could have worded it better tho, should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `VirtualAlloc` is failing. You would have figured that out if you checked its return value.

The reason it's failing comes directly from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `MEM_PHYSICAL` must be used with `MEM_RESERVE` and no other values. You likely don't want `MEM_PHYSICAL` anyway, it has to do with [AWE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Removing the flag will make the allocation succeed.

The call to `VirtualProtect` is unnecessary.

The following should work:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    VirtualAlloc((void*)0x50000000,0x1000,MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_READWRITE);
    *((int*)0x50000000) = 5;
}
```

Comment: @Gizmo, hm, so I told you to remove MEM_PHYSICAL, and you removed MEM_RESERVE as well?